# Custom rounded button with outline

Tags: vb.net, winforms, custom-controls

I am tring to create a custom button width rounded corner and a white outline which follows its shape. On the OnPaint event I've added the following code.

```
Public Class RoundedButton
    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)
        Dim grPath As GraphicsPath = New GraphicsPath(FillMode.Winding)
        grPath.AddArc(0, 0, ClientSize.Height, ClientSize.Height, 90, 180)
        grPath.AddLine(grPath.GetLastPoint, New Point(ClientSize.Width - grPath.GetLastPoint.X * 2, 0))
        grPath.AddArc(New RectangleF(grPath.GetLastPoint, New Size(ClientSize.Height, ClientSize.Height)), 270, 180)
        grPath.CloseFigure()

        Me.Region = New Region(grPath)

        Dim mypen As New Pen(Color.White, 2)
        mypen.Alignment = PenAlignment.Inset
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(mypen, grPath)
    End Sub
End Class
```

If I try to use it in a form, it works only if Backcolor property is set to Transparent. If not I can't see the pen path.
I would like to change the backcolor without loose the rounded white border of the pen.
I would like to obtain something like this:
[image]

Comment: Where's the white part?  I only see a Red pen.  Unclear what help you are asking for.  Never set the Region property in a paint event.  Dispose your drawing objects, too.

Comment: Ops, the red was just for test. I've updated the post so I think it's clear now what I want to obtain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With all projects that you want custom buttons, it is usually easiest to curve a PictureBox with a picture of your button, then using your coding language (VB.NET, C#, C++) to add an on click function to make the action.

Here is a mini example using VB.NET:

```
Private Sub pictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles pictureBox1.Click
    Process.start("http://stackoverflow.com")
End Sub
```

Hope I helped,
Matt